# Register implementation based on lifestyle with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm using the Simple Injector as my IoC container. I would like to inject in my classes logger based on existence of execution scope. There should be one default logger (singleton) and others based on my context.

I tried already something like this:

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogger),
    x => typeof(NContextLogger<>).MakeGenericType(
        x.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Scoped,
    x => container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() != null);

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogger),
    x => typeof(NLogger<>).MakeGenericType(x.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    x => container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() == null);
```

The problem is with creating any instance of `NContextLogger<>`. Because when it creates `NLogger<>` which is singleton, Simple Injector is not trying to create instance of `NContextLogger`.

Comment: I must say I find this a quite odd requirement. Why do want to resolve objects outside the context of an active execution context scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate supplied to `RegisterConditional` can't be used for runtime decision making, since the results of the predicate are cached and burned into the expression tree and the compiled delegates. The availability of the <strike>`GetCurrentExecutionContextScope()`</strike> `Lifestyle.Scoped.GetCurrentScope(Container)` however is a runtime decision.

Decisions based on runtime conditions should not be made during construction of the object graph (for the same reason as [runtime data shouldn't be injected into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)).

Instead of making decisions based on runtime conditions during the building of the object graph, these decisions should be postponed till after the object graph is built. The most obvious way to do this is by introducing a proxy class:

```
public sealed class ProxyLogger<T> : ILogger
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public ProxyLogger(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    // Implement ILogger method(s)
    public void Log(string message) => Logger.Log(message);
    
    private ILogger Logger =>
        Lifestyle.Scoped.GetCurrentScope(container) == null
            ? container.GetInstance<NLogger<T>>()
            : container.GetInstance<NContextLogger<T>>();
}
```

Using this proxy class, you can make the following registrations to satisfy your requirements:

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogger),
    c => typeof(ProxyLogger<>).MakeGenericType(
        x.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);
    
container.Register(typeof(NLogger<>), typeof(NLogger<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register(typeof(NContextLogger<>), typeof(NContextLogger<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Comment: Thanks. ProxyLogger is thing i were looking for.